# Update multiple user details when new user is registered in laravel php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here is register new user code in php laravel-5.4  mysql

[image]

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $epincheck = $request->epin;

    if (Epin::where('epin', '=', '75656565')->exists()) {

        //   DB::table('epins')->where('epin', $epincheck)->delete();
        $post = new Admin();
        $post->name = $request->name;
        $post->email = $request->email;
        $post->plan = $request->plan;
        $post->epin = $epincheck;
        $post->ref = $request->ref;
        $post->mobile = $request->mobile;
        $post->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $post->save();

        //other trims
        $referal_user = $request->ref;
        $referal_email = DB::table('admins')->where('mobile', $referal_user)->first();
        $referal_id = $referal_email->id;

        $update_ref_user = Admin::find($referal_id);
        $previous_users_left = $referal_email->user_left;
        $previous_users_right = $referal_email->user_right;
        $direct_referal = $referal_email->direct_referal;
        $list_all_right_user = $referal_email->user_listing_right;
        $list_all_left_user = $referal_email->user_listing_left;
        $left_count = $referal_email->no_user_left;
        $right_count = $referal_email->no_user_right;
        $direct_count = $referal_email->no_direct_referal;

        if(!$previous_users_right && $previous_users_left )
        {
            $update_ref_user->user_right =  $request->email ;
            $update_ref_user->no_user_right =  $right_count+1 ;
            $update_ref_user->user_listing_right =   $request->email . ' , ' . $list_all_right_user ;
            $update_ref_user->save();

            $last_updated_id = $update_ref_user->id;
            $update_up_line = DB::table('admins')->where('id', $last_updated_id);
            $update_up_line_list = $update_up_line->id;

            //  $update_up_line = Admin::find($last_updated_id);

            /* $update_up_line_update->user_listing_right = $request->email;
             $update_up_line-> save();*/

            //looping get referal id -> find referee -> update ;
            //find last  referal id -> find referee -> update ;
            //find referal id -> find referee -> update ;
            //find referal id -> find referee -> update ;
            //find referal id -> find referee -> update ;
            //when there is no ref_no loop ends
            //stop when count ends;
        }

        if(!$previous_users_left)
        {
            $update_ref_user->user_left =  $request->email ;
            $update_ref_user->no_user_left =  $left_count + 1 ;
            $update_ref_user->user_listing_left =  $request->email . ' , ' . $list_all_left_user  ;

            $update_ref_user->save();

        }
        if($previous_users_left && $previous_users_right)
        {
            $update_ref_user->direct_referal = $direct_referal . ' , ' . $request->email ;
            $update_ref_user->no_direct_referal = $direct_count +1 ;

            $update_ref_user->save();

        }
        //sms gatewat
        /*Send SMS using PHP*/

        return redirect('/admin/login');
        // \Session::flash('msg', 'Changes Saved.' );

    }

    else {
        echo "You Have Entered Invalid Pin";
    }
}
```

When a new user is registered he inputs reference code in signup form.
I want that when a new user is registered with mobile->'123' and reference number '987' then 
step 1) find "reference number" of new registered user then search "reference number" in "mobile" field of all registered user then add 50% of $200(it is currency)to his income add previous user's name in a database field name="user_under"

step 2) find "reference number" of previous user then search "reference number" in "mobile" field of all registered user then add 30% of $200(it is currency)to his income add previous user's name in a database field name="user_under"

step 3) find "reference number" of previous user then search "reference number" in "mobile" field of all registered user then add 10% of $200(it is currency) to his income and add previous user's name in a database field name="user_under"

step 4) find "reference number" of previous user then search "reference number" in "mobile" field of all registered user then add previous user's name in a database field name="user_under"

******step 4 continues till reference number= null/ no value

I cannot understand  how to apply the logic

#####edit

@jeffrey

here is manual code for 5th level need to automate it using while recursive

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{

    $post = new Admin();
        $post->name = 'nill';
        $post->email = $request->email;
        $post->plan = 'uuiuii';
        $post->epin = '9999';
        $post->ref = $request->ref;
        $post->mobile = $request->mobile;
        $post->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $post->save();


    $referal_user = $request->ref;
    $referal_email = DB::table('admins')->where('mobile', $referal_user)->first();
    $referal_id = $referal_email->id;
    $right_count = $referal_email->no_user_right;
    $list_all_right_user = $referal_email->user_listing_right;

    //first update


        $update_ref_user = Admin::find($referal_id);
    $get_user_previous = $referal_email->user_listing_right;
        $update_ref_user->user_right = $request->email;
        $update_ref_user->no_user_right = $right_count + 1;
        $update_ref_user->user_listing_right = $request->email . ' , ' . $get_user_previous;
        $update_ref_user->save();
        $last_updated_id = $update_ref_user->ref;

    ///next
    ///
   // echo $last_updated_id;

    $ref_previous2 =  $last_updated_id;
    if($ref_previous2 ) {
        $referal_email2 = DB::table('admins')->where('mobile', $last_updated_id)->first();
        $get_user_previous2 = $referal_email2->user_listing_right;
        $update_ref_user_id_2 = $referal_email2->id;
        $update_ref_user2 = Admin::find($update_ref_user_id_2);
        $update_ref_user2->user_right = 'jhkkkj';
        $update_ref_user2->no_user_right = $right_count + 1;
        $update_ref_user2->user_listing_right = $request->email . ' , ' . $get_user_previous2;
        $update_ref_user2->save();

        $ref_previous3 = $update_ref_user2->ref;
        if($ref_previous3 ) {
            $last_updated_id3 = $update_ref_user2->ref;
            $referal_email3 = DB::table('admins')->where('mobile', $last_updated_id3)->first();
            $get_user_previous3 = $referal_email3->user_listing_right;
            $update_ref_user_id_3 = $referal_email3->id;
            $update_ref_user3 = Admin::find($update_ref_user_id_3);
            $update_ref_user3->user_right = 'jhkkkj';
            $update_ref_user3->no_user_right = $right_count + 1;
            $update_ref_user3->user_listing_right = $request->email . ' , ' . $get_user_previous3;
            $update_ref_user3->save();



            $ref_previous4 = $update_ref_user3->ref;
            if($ref_previous4 ) {

                $last_updated_id4 = $update_ref_user3->ref;
                $referal_email4 = DB::table('admins')->where('mobile', $last_updated_id4)->first();
                $get_user_previous4 = $referal_email4->user_listing_right;
                $update_ref_user_id_4 = $referal_email4->id;
                $update_ref_user4 = Admin::find($update_ref_user_id_4);
                $update_ref_user4->user_right = 'jhkkkj';
                $update_ref_user4->no_user_right = $right_count + 1;
                $update_ref_user4->user_listing_right = $request->email . ' , ' . $get_user_previous4;
                $update_ref_user4->save();



                $ref_previous5 = $update_ref_user4->ref;
                if($ref_previous5 ) {
                    $last_updated_id5 = $update_ref_user4->ref;
                    $referal_email5 = DB::table('admins')->where('mobile', $last_updated_id5)->first();
                    $get_user_previous5 = $referal_email5->user_listing_right;
                    $update_ref_user_id_5 = $referal_email4->id;
                    $update_ref_user5 = Admin::find($update_ref_user_id_5);
                    $update_ref_user5->user_right = 'jhkkkj';
                    $update_ref_user5->no_user_right = $right_count + 1;
                    $update_ref_user5->user_listing_right = $request->email . ' , ' . $get_user_previous5;
                    $update_ref_user5->save();

                }
            }
        }
    }
    //next




    //4th update



    ///five
    ///
    ///





   return redirect('/admin/register2');

    }
```

#############here is the solution

```
$referal_user = $request->ref;
    $referal_email = DB::table('admins')->where('mobile', $referal_user)->first();
    $referal_id = $referal_email->id;
    $right_count = $referal_email->no_user_right;
    $list_all_right_user = $referal_email->user_listing_right;
    $ref = $request->ref;
    $mobile = $request->mobile;
    $user_listing_left = $referal_email->user_listing_left;
    while( $refUser = Admin::where('mobile', $ref)->first() )
    {
        $refUser->user_left = $request->email;
        $refUser->user_listing_left = $refUser->user_listing_left . "," .$request->email;
        $refUser->save();

        // Update $ref to find the next guy
        $ref = $refUser->ref;

    }
```

Comment: After reading your question and looking at your screenshot description I feel confused.

Comment: @ventiseis in screenshot I just explained how it database will update.see from down.
          //looping get referal id of new  registered user -> find referee -> update(1) ;
            //find last  referal id (i.e 1)-> find referee -> update(2) ;
            //find referal id(2) -> find referee -> update(3) ;
            //find referal id(3) -> find referee -> update ;
            //find referal id -> find referee -> update ;
            //when there is no ref_no loop ends
            //stop when count ends;

Comment: I don't understand the question fully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the question fully, but I'll give it a shot.

`Recursive` is the key word here. You seem to want to go up the tree of reference, and depending on what level you are, add a certain amount of $ to that person. I do however not understand what you mean by *add previous user's name in a database field name="user_under"* the field is not visible as well...

```
$percentages = [50, 30, 10, 5, 2, 1, 0.5];
$iteration = 0;
$ref = $request->ref;
while( $refUser = Admin::where('ref', $ref)->first() && $percentages[$iteration] )
{
    $refUser->income += floor( 200 * $percentages[$iteration++] );
    $refUser->save();

    // Update $ref to find the next guy
    $ref = $refUser->ref;
}
```

The second condition for the while loop, is to make sure that if the $percentages array is shorted than the tree in the database, it won't break and quits giving money. You may of course extend the array.

I hope this is what you asked, else leave a comment.